# Confused with -Include parameter of the Get-ChildItem cmdlet

Tags: powershell, include, get-childitem

From documentation:

> -Include
>
> Retrieves only the specified items.
>   The value of this parameter qualifies
>   the Path parameter. Enter a path
>   element or pattern, such as "*.txt".
>   Wildcards are permitted.
>
> The Include parameter is effective only when the command
>   includes the Recurse parameter or the
>   path leads to the contents of a
>   directory, such as C:\Windows*, where
>   the wildcard character specifies the
>   contents of the C:\Windows directory.

My first understanding was:

```
c:\test\a.txt
c:\test\b.txt
```

So to get 'a.txt' and 'b.txt' I can write:

```
gci -Path "c:\test\*" -Include "*.txt"
```

And this works. But now consider such hierarchy:

```
c:\test\a.txt
c:\test\b.txt
c:\test\c.txt\c.txt
```

The same command returns:
   a.txt, b.txt, c.txt

The actual logic seems to be:

> -Include used to match all entities specified by -Path. If matched element
>   is a file - return it. If matched
>   element is a folder, look inside and
>   return matching first level children.

Also, the documentation say:

> The Include parameter is effective only when the command
>   includes the Recurse parameter or the
>   path leads to the contents of a
>   directory...

This is wrong as well. E.g.

```
gci -Path "c:\test" -Include "*.txt"
```

It returns nothing, while without -Include I get folder content. So -Include is definitely "effective". What really happens here? The -Path specify the "c:\test", and the -Include tries to match this path. As "*.txt" does not match "test", so nothing returned. But look at this:

```
gci -Path "c:\test" -Include "*t"
```

It returns a.txt, b.txt and c.txt as "*t" matched "test" and matched all child items.

After all, even knowing how Include works now, I don't understand when to use it. Why do I need it look to inside subfolders? Why should it be so complex?

Answer (score 15):

You're confusing the use of -include.  The -include flag is applied to the path, not the contents of the path.  Without the use of the recursive flag, the only path that is in question is the path you specify.  This is why the last example you gave works, the path `c:\test` has a t in the path and hence matches `"*t"`.

You can verify this by trying the following

```
gci -path "c:\test" -in *e*
```

This will still produce all of the children in the directory yet it matches none of their names.

The reason that -include is more effective with the recurse parameter is that you end up applying the wildcard against every path in the hierarchy.

Comment: I am using PowerShell-v2.0-CTP3, and your example produces empty set.

Comment: @alex2k8,  Not sure what to say here.  I've tried this example on 1.0 and a later 2.0 build, both produce the same results.

Comment: @Jared, this is strange. Please, can you try gci -path c:\* -in *. I see children of the c:\ and all it's subfolders one level down. Here is the similar description http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32624832/getchilditem-include-qu.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Try the -filter parameter (it has support for only one extension):

dir -filter *.txt

Comment: Filter is slightly different because it is a provider specific implementation.  It's typically more efficient because it occurs before the data is returned.  But it does have a different implementation for every drive provider in PowerShell.  Hence there can be subtle differences in the matching algorithm.

Comment: I agree, though in this case we're talking about the file system provider. Thnaks for the comment.

Answer (score 5):

Tacking on to [JaredPar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790796/confused-with-include-parameter-of-the-get-childitem-cmdlet/790895#790895), in order to do pattern matching with Get-ChildItem, you can use common shell wildcards.

For example:

```
get-childitem "c:\test\t?st.txt"
```

where the "?" is a wildcard matching any one character or

```
get-childitem "c:\test\*.txt"
```

which will match any file name ending in ".txt".

This should get you the "simpler" behavior you were looking for.

Comment: Isn't the issue here that you can only get a single extension?  -Include is string[] allowing for multiple matching variations.

Thanks, Ben

Answer (score 3):

I just asked a similar question and got three quick replies concerning the [Get-Help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849696.aspx) for Get-ChildItem.

> The answer is in the full description of the command (get-help get-childitem -full):
>
> > The Include parameter is effective
> > only when the command includes the
> > Recurse parameter or the path leads to
> > the contents of a directory, such as
> > C:\Windows\*, where the wildcard
> > character specifies the contents of
> > the C:\Windows directory.
>
> So the following would work without recurse.
>
> ```
> PS C:\foo> Get-childitem -path "c:\foo\*" -Include *.txt
> ```

From Stack Overflow question *[PowerShell Scripting - Get-ChildItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370210/)*.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Ben, actually my question was a bit different. Notice, that your example will return .txt files from the foo folder, BUT it can also unexpectedly return files and even folders from for example "c:\foo\dir.txt" directory. Try such hierarchy: c:\foo\dir.txt\file.txt and c:\foo\dir.txt\dir2.txt\file2.txt. You'll get: file.txt and dir2.txt!

Answer (score 1):

Including `\*` at the end of the path should work around the issue

```
PS C:\logfiles> Get-ChildItem .\* -include *.log
```

This should return .log files from the current working directory (`C:\logfiles`)

Alex's example above indicates that a directory with the name foo.log would also be returned. When I tried it, it wasn't but it's 6 years later and that could be from PS updates.

However, you can use the child item `Mode` to exclude directories I think.

```
PS C:\logfiles> Get-Childitem .\* -include *.log | where-object {$_.mode -notmatch "d"}
```

This should exclude anything with the 'directory' mode set.

Comment: Including \* at the end of the path does not always work.  I know of no way to specify an -Include value to match files that have no filename extension.  Specifying * as an -Include pattern will match such files, but makes Get-ChildItem act recursively.  If -Include behaved the same way as Exclude, it would be easy.

Answer (score 1):

get-childitem -include only works with -recursive or a wildcard in the path.  I consider this a bug [Thought it was different in PS 6].

Comment: It's not, still needed to add `\*` to make it work.