# Get-ChildItem not listing files on Win Server 2003 but works fine on XP

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to return a list of files based on a filter of cash_st_export*.txt but it doesn't work!   If I run gci *.dll on an XP workstation in the default Powershell working directory it works fine.

```
PS C:\Program Files\iNovah 2 [Test]\WebServices\iNovah2WebService\ExportFiles> 
gci cash_st_export*.txt

PS C:\Program Files\iNovah 2 [Test]\WebServices\iNovah2WebService\ExportFiles> 
gci *.txt

PS C:\Program Files\iNovah 2 [Test]\WebServices\iNovah2WebService\ExportFiles> 
ls


Directory: C:\Program Files\iNovah 2 [Test]\WebServices\iNovah2WebService\ExportFiles


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                               
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                               
d----          4/7/2011   2:23 PM            Archive                                                                                            
-a---         3/24/2011   6:30 PM          0 cash_sei_export_03242011_183015278.txt                                                             
-a---         3/25/2011   6:30 PM        294 cash_sei_export_03252011_183047903.txt                                                             
-a---         3/28/2011   6:30 PM        462 cash_sei_export_03282011_18302584.txt                                                              
-a---         3/29/2011   6:30 PM          0 cash_sei_export_03292011_183040422.txt                                                             
-a---         3/30/2011   9:38 AM        336 cash_sei_export_03302011_093800868.txt                                                             
-a---         3/30/2011   6:30 PM          0 cash_sei_export_03302011_18300400.txt                                                              
-a---         3/31/2011   2:04 PM          0 cash_sei_export_03312011_140407388.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gci * -include cash_st_export*.txt
```

Anyway cash **st** export seems not exist in the result of ls, but cash **sei** export.

---

Similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370210/powershell-scripting-get-childitem).

Check also [MS doc.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347686.aspx)

---

I've tested now gci on my W2K8 server and works fine.
You need to use `*` only if you use `include` without `force`.

```
gci * -include add*.txt
```

Using this:

```
gci add*.txt
```

is actually the same as:

```
gci -path add*.txt
```

All this applies to Powershell v2.0 and (I think) to 1.0 also.

**NOTE**: your workaround in the comment still refers to **sei** files.

Comment: the directory listing was huge and there are cash_st_export*.txt files further down.   But for clarification I ran:   "gci . -include cash_sei_export*.txt" and it returns no results.

Comment: I was able to cobble this together to achieve my result:   gci | where-object { $_.Name -match "cash_sei" }        I'm going to leave this open to see if anyone can explain why I have to resort to this to make it work.

Comment: I've found that When using the `Include` parameter without the `Recurse` parameter, the path must point to contents, not a container. Try the new edit.