# Powershell 5 Get-ChildItem LiteralPath doesn't work with Include anymore

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Right now I updated to Windows 10 TH2 Build 10586 with PowerShell 5.0.10586.0

Now I got a problem with Get-ChildItem

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Force -Recurse -Include *.txt
```

This returns ALL files in $path even they are not .txt.
This was working before the update.
When I change it to

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse -Include *.txt
```

it works again. But that's not what I want.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what's $path in there, does it have a \ at the end?

Comment: I have tested both. With and without \ at the end. Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The bug still affects _Windows PowerShell_, but has fortunately been fixed in PowerShell (Core) as of (at least) v7.0. However there is still questionable by-design behavior in the absence of `-Recurse`: `-Include` and `-Exclude` only apply to the _input_ paths, not to their _children_; the workaround is to use `Get-ChildItem * -Include ... / -Exclude ...` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I *never* use `-Include` or `-Exclude` anymore.  I always pipe through `Where-Object`.  I don't know if the author of `-Include` and `-Exclude` was insane or if there's a problem with the underlying .Net provider, but they're flaky as hell.

I'm on 5.0.10240.16384.

```
gci -Path $path -Include *.txt -Force
```

Returns nothing.

```
gci -LiteralPath $path -Include *.txt -Force
```

Returns everything in `$path`.

```
gci -LiteralPath $path -Include *.txt -Force -Recurse
gci -Path $path -Include *.txt -Force -Recurse
```

Both return *.txt in `$path` and all subfolders.

So what's the proper behavior supposed to be?  Does the `-Recurse` flag modify how `-Include` works?  I don't know.  I no longer care.  I'm not going to deal with that kind of behavior.  I just use this:

```
gci -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.txt' }
```

I rely on `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate files and folders *and that's it*.  Just give me the objects and I'll filter them.  Like all the old `Remove-Item -Recurse` bugs, there's something there that just doesn't work the way people expect it to.

Comment: @MarcFauser Hm, you're right.  [The doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) also says that `-Include` modifies the `-Path` argument and says nothing at all about the `-LiteralPath` argument.  Christ, why doesn't this cmdlet emit errors for unsupported syntax?  And I have no idea what to make of Example 3, which explicitly talks about using `-Path` and `-Include` without `-Recurse`!  Again I'm left asking, "What's the proper behavior supposed to be?"  I'd probably post on Microsoft Connect, for all the good it will do.

Comment: @BaconBits probably knows this 2 years on, but for people visiting the answer is that the cmdlet doesn't know about unsupported syntax - it just passes them down to the PS Provider subsystem - wildcard behaviour for the filesystem PS Provider is different from the registry provider and from the ActiveDirectory provider, etc. And I suspect that's also why it's "flaky as hell" - because the filesystem wildcards are backwards compatible to Windows 3 or MS-DOS era. It's also why the docs can't say much but "qualifies the path" because it depends on the PSProvider implementation.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler flaky as hell and probably much more efficient - especially if you have a folder with many files and you want to filter most of them out.

Comment: I am discovering this 7 years later and this bug still exists -_-

Comment: @user206904 Yes, even in PS v7.3 I still see unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `-Filter` does not seem to have this issue. This works:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Force -Recurse -Filter *.txt
```

`Filter` is also [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790796/confused-with-include-parameter-of-the-get-childitem-cmdlet/791188#comment601560_791188), because it is used by the underlying provider (as opposed to `Include` which is applied by PowerShell itself, much like a `where` clause added by your code).

However [`Filter` only accepts one pattern parameter, whereas `Include` supports multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18626464/67824/).

Comment: Unfortunately -Filter can only handle one filter, not multiple includes

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a regression. I submitted it as [v5 regression: Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath -Recurse ignores -Include and gets all items](http://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11168994-v5-regression-get-childitem-literalpath-recurse)