# Windows10/Powershell: How to use -include parameter when using Get-Childitem?

Tags: powershell

When using "-filter":

`Get-ChildItem -file -filter "*.txt" | foreach-object { write-host $_.FullName` }

I get a listing of the 4 .txt files that's in the current folder.

I tried using "-include"

```
Get-ChildItem -file -include *.txt | foreach-object { write-host $_.FullName }
Get-ChildItem -file -include *txt | foreach-object { write-host $_.FullName }
```

and I get nothing. I tried with and without the "-file" parameter and it makes no difference.

I've looked at various guides/examples (ss64.com/TechNet and etc) and supposedly I am doing it right.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684178/powershell-5-get-childitem-literalpath-doesnt-work-with-include-anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `Get-Help` page for `Get-ChildItem`:

> The `-Include` parameter is effective only when the command includes the `-Recurse` parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory, such as `C:\Windows*`, where the "`*`" wildcard character specifies the contents of the `C:\Windows` directory.

You'll note that you *don't* get a syntax error if you specify `-include` and don't specify `-recurse` in spite of the fact that whatever it does is literally undefined.  You'll also note that `C:\Windows*` is not a normal wildcard expression for "all files in the `C:\Windows` directory".  It's a wildcard expression for "all items that start with 'Windows' in the `C:\` directory and may or may not have an extension".  I have no idea what the authors of `Get-ChildItem` think this parameter is supposed to do.  They've done a fantastically poor job of documenting it and implementing it.

Consequently, I avoid the `-Include` parameter as broken/badly documented.  I don't know what it's supposed to do that `-Filter` doesn't.  I've read articles about what it does exactly.  It "passes the value to the underlying provider to filter at that level" in some manner.  I don't know why they assume that a sysadmin will know what that really means.  My understanding is that it's the difference between calling `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` on each directory item and calling `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles('*.txt')` on each directory item, but most sysadmins aren't going to know what that means.  However, it's so oddly behaved that I don't trust it, so even though I am about 95% sure of what it does... I *still* never use it.

Instead, I just pipe to `Where-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -file | Where-Object Extension -eq '.txt' | [...]
```

Also note that `Get-ChildItem` is broken with `-LiteralPath`, `-Recurse` and `-Include` in some versions of PowerShell, and will instead return all items.

Compare:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSHOME *.exe -Recurse # works
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSHOME -Include *.exe -Recurse # works
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSHOME -Include *.exe -Recurse # does NOT work
```

Issue reported [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3730) for v6.

Comment: weird that technet's own examples don't use recurse parameter. Thanks!

Comment: @mrjayviper `-Include` and `-Exclude` also get ignored when you use `-LiteralPath`.  I forgot about that one, but it's been a bug for ages in some versions.

Comment: `-Filter` is limited to one pattern string (`-Include` supports multiple). And as you implied, `-Filter` is both typically  more efficient and works properly with `-LiterlPath` and `-Recurse`. So to sum up, if you only need one pattern, use `-Filter`. If you need multiple patterns use `where` as you suggested (which is basically equivalent to `-Include` anyway as the filtering is done by PowerShell rather than the underlying provider).

Answer (score 1):

These work for me without recursion:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Athom\Desktop\*.txt"


Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*.txt"
```

Or Just add the recursion parameter:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Include *.txt -Recurse
```