# Powershell Get-ChildItem extended (non * or ?) wildcard

Tags: powershell, wildcard, get-childitem

I have no trouble with `Get-ChildItem` using * as a wildcard, but I wonder if it can be made to work with more refined wild cards. Given a file like `C:\Folder\journal.0001.txt` I would want to use the wildcard `C:\Folder\journal.####.txt` to get all "regular" journal files, but skip the ones named with this format `journal.0000.worker1.log`. Using the wildcard in the path throws an error that the path doesn't exist, and replacing the file bit with a simple `*` and the using `journal.####.txt` as a filter or include doesn't work.
I do see that `journal.????.txt` works, but that would potentially grab `journal.ABCD.txt` should it exist. And I haven't even started playing with character sets.

Comment: Due to the sometimes huge differences between versions, especially core vs previous, use the tag indicating the version of PS instead of the general `powershell` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compared to RegEx wildcard patterns have a limited metacharacter set, and no quantifiers I know of, It does support character ranges like:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\06-11-21\journal.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
```

Oddly, this only works as part of the path. It doesn't seem to work when specified as an argument to `-Filter` or `-Include`.

[about_Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.1)

You can post filter the files using `Where-Object` or a `For-EachObject` loop with RegEx if you need more flexibility.

Comment: As for `-Filter`: it uses the file-system's wildcard expressions, which don't support character sets/ranges (`[...]`); as for `-Include`: unfortunately, it only acts on the leaf components of the _input path_, not its children - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).

Answer (score 0):

I have a saved [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684178/powershell-5-get-childitem-literalpath-doesnt-work-with-include-anymore) that discusses problems with `-Include` and `-Exclude`. I got there as I had problems with filtering, and ever since I use `Where-Object` for that purpose. I dont't know if there is a more compact way to do this, but I used it like this with a multi-parameter file search:

```
Get-ChildItem ... |
Where-Object {$_.Extension -in $FileExtensionIN -or $FileExtensionIN.Count -eq 0} |
Where-Object {$_.Extension -notin $FileExtensionNOTIN -or $FileExtensionNOTIN.Count -eq 0} |
Where-Object {$_.Name -match $FileNameMATCH -or $FileNameMATCH -eq ""} |
Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch $FileNameNOTMATCH -or $FileNameNOTMATCH -eq ""} |
...
```

It is not compact, but at least also not cryptic.

Comment: The linked problem is a bug specific to `-LiteralPath` vs. `-Path` that plagues _Windows PowerShell_, but has fortunately been fixed in PowerShell (Core) as of (at least) v7.0. However there is still questionable by-design behavior in the absence of `-Recurse`: `-Include` and `-Exclude` only apply to the _input_ paths, not to their _children_; the workaround is to use `Get-ChildItem * -Include ... / -Exclude ...` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for your input. This also strengthens me to use post-filtering, as there are still caveats & workarounds with a lot of explanations which is so tiring that I don't want to test... nevertheless your pedantic coverage of use-cases is impressive - keep up the good work! :). The second thing is of course, that the whole thing needed to be checked twice, in v5.1 & core...

Comment: All sorts of great info here. In my case I can't use it in this particular situation, but noted for other situations. And as to WHY I can't use it, the specific issue I have is that I am working with path data that is provided by the user in an XML file, and I need to limit my data to a single data item for now. So any wild card MUST be part of the path. In future I may be able to support additional elements in the XML to support a filter value, but for now I can't. So for now the solution @Steven provided is my best option. It covers 95% of situations, just not as tersely as I had hoped for.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó, yes, the situation is still a mess, unfortunately. The potential problem with post-filtering - while sometimes unavoidable to implemented more sophisticated matching - is diminished performance, which can matter in large directory trees. At least that's the theory - in practice, as of PowerShell 7.2 `-Include` / `-Exclude` are _slower_ than post-filtering(!), but that can and should be fixed - see [GitHub issue #8662](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8662) (sigh). `-Filter` - _if_ its abilities are sufficient in a given scenario - is always fastest.

Comment: I've updated the guidance in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/45375), but I can definitely see why one wouldn't bother and just use post-filtering instead.  I'll attempt a tl;dr here: If you're using `-Recurse`, everything works as expected, in both editions. Otherwise, if you're using _PowerShell v7+_ and the input paths are literals, use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` (does _not_ work in _Windows PowerShell_).
Otherwise, switch to `Get-Item` and append `\*` to the input paths (passed to `-Path`).