# Get_ChildItem get list of files in a path not recursively

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am writing a PowerShell script to get all the items in a particular folder path specified. I am using following command :

```
$fileName= Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\to\Bin"  -Force -Include User.Base.Tests.*.dll
```

I am not using `-Recurse` but it is returning empty results. I want result from only `Bin` folder not from sub folder. If I user `-Recurse` command it will give me results from sub folders as well which I don't want.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You are just asking for a list of files with that wildcard. There is no real reason to use -include for that. Can you state your reason for deciding to use -Include for a this?

Answer (score 2):

We have to include a wildcard character in the path as below:

```
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Path\to\Bin\*" -Force -Include User.Base.Tests.*.dll
```

*The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory

See: [Confused with -Include parameter of the Get-ChildItem cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790796/confused-with-include-parameter-of-the-get-childitem-cmdlet)

Answer (score 0):

Without the -Include the below works as expected. However, with a file name like that, you want to quote stuff with those constructs. IMHO.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\temp User.Base.Tests.*.dll | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name                 
----          ------------- ------ ----                 
-a----  04-Apr-20     00:45      0 User.Base.Tests.1.dll
-a----  04-Apr-20     00:45      0 User.Base.Tests.2.dll
#>


Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\temp' 'User.Base.Tests.*.dll' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
# Results

    Directory: D:\temp


Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name                 
----          ------------- ------ ----                 
-a----  04-Apr-20     00:45      0 User.Base.Tests.1.dll
-a----  04-Apr-20     00:45      0 User.Base.Tests.2.dll
#>
```

Comment: -include has to be there as there are any other files as well