# Why get-childitem with wildcards are not easy to use?

Tags: powershell

what is wrong on this:
`get-childitem "$([System.Environment]::SystemDirectory)" -Include ('*.exe','*.dll')`

and why this works:
`get-childitem "$([System.Environment]::SystemDirectory)\*" -Include ('*.exe','*.dll')`

from which line of get-childitem docu should I understand this effect?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790796/confused-with-include-parameter-of-the-get-childitem-cmdlet.  The wildcard is a requirement for `-path` when using the `-include` parameter

Comment: ["*The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the contents of an item, such as `C:\Windows\*`, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the `C:\Windows directory.`*"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1#parameters)